# git submodule tracking a tag

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know how to add a submodule that tracks a branch (`-b branchname`) but I want to know if there is a similar functionality to track a tag.

Let say I have a tag for a specific project in a submodule repo. I add new features in the submodule repo and pull up the tag to a certain commit. I want the project that is using the submodule to track the tag without having to have an extra commit in the project repo.

Is this possible ?

Regards

Comment: are you moving the tag in the submodule? Like for instance tag "LikeMe" is moved from commit AAAAAA to BBBBBB and you want to automatically track this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, even with the `-b` option, Git submodules always specify a specific *commit* by raw hash ID.  The `-b` option is notable for how Git doesn't really use it, in other words.<sup>1</sup>   But it's not what you want anyway: you want a specific *tag*.

Now, the thing about a Git tag is this: *it's never supposed to move*.  What that means, once it's stripped down to bare-bones ideas, is that a tag name is just a human-readable name for some specific raw hash ID, and it should *always* mean *that* hash ID.  This distinguishes tag names from branch names: branch names are names for a specific hash ID, but the hash ID for the name `br1`, with `br1` being a branch name, is *supposed to change over time*.

Another way to phrase this is:

- A *branch* name always means *the **latest** commit*, rather than *one particular commit regardless of what's happened recently*.
- A *tag* name always means *that one particular commit we picked out on that particular day*.  In essence, this is the *opposite* of a branch name.

But, given the above, and given the way submodules work—the superproject specifies the submodule commit by raw hash ID—there's no *point* in using a tag name.  If tag name `tag1` means commit `a123456` forever, then the only reason to use the name `tag1` instead of the raw hash ID is for human consumption ... and a submodule reference isn't for *human* consumption, it's for *Git*.  So you just want to pick a commit and stick with it, which is what a submodule already does.

In other words, don't bother.  The only time this would make any difference is if you move tags, and you're not supposed to move tags.  If you *are* moving tags—picking a different commit now and then—you're misusing them: the things that *are* supposed to move are *branch names*, not tag names.  Stop doing that.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously, Git *does* record the branch name somewhere.  You can then get Git to use it.  The method is not obvious, though, and `git submodule update` is a little weird with it.  The real key here is that the superproject Git repository keeps the submodule repository on a *detached HEAD* at all times.  Even if you specify a branch name, the submodule is still using detached-HEAD mode.  So it's not actually *using* the branch name—not directly, anyway.  The idea, not necessarily terribly well implemented, is that the superproject Git can command the submodule Git to `git fetch` from some *third* Git repository, then use `git rev-parse` to translate some remote-tracking name related to the branch name into a hash ID, and thereby somehow arrive at the right hash ID to use for the detached HEAD checkout in the submodule.

This is all rather cumbersome and complicated.  Submodule support is being improved as an ongoing project, and it might someday become simpler and saner, but for now my personal recommendation is that if you want branch-like behavior from "submodules", don't use `git submodule` itself directly here.  Just enter the submodule, treat it as a regular Git repository, run `git checkout` or `git switch` as usual, and then do your work there to bring it up to date and have the right commit checked out.  Then, exit the submodule back to the superproject, and use `git add` to update the superproject repository's index so as to record the new correct hash ID.

If you do all this my way, you don't need the `-b` option at all.  You can use it as a reminder-to-self, if you like.

If you have a sufficiently modern Git, `git submodule update --remote` can simplify this somewhat.  I know this didn't work well in Git 1.5/1.6; it *might* be OK as far back as 1.7 or 1.8, which would make it work fairly well today, since even the older Linux distributions now come with 1.7 or 1.8 versions.  It's probably fine since about 2.5, about the time `git worktree` appeared.

<sup>2</sup>Of course, with Git, *you* are in control.  If you have a really damn good reason to move tags around, and are aware of how it can break the heads of other *people* who are using your repository, you can in fact move tags around.  But then you'll need to move the submodule commits around by making new commits.  See also footnote 1.